# Kernel panic after upgrading from wheezy to jessie

Tags: debian, upgrade, kernel-panic

I upgraded my system from wheezy to jessie. 
However, I am not able to boot using the latest kernel
that was installed with jessie. 
I get the  following error:

```
Loading, please wait...
/init: conf/conf.d/resume: line 1 syntax error: unexpected "("
... Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init exitcode=0x00000200
... 
... CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ctk25-2
... Hardware name: Dell Inc. Precision Workstation T5400 ... BIOS A11 04/30/2012
...
...
...
```

Here are two photographs of the screen during the boot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3F6j.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnV1n.png). 
Neither is perfectly clear; look at either one, or both, or neither,
as you prefer.

I can boot with older kernel 3.2.0-4 using sysvinit from GRUB.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. Upgrade installed a new path to swap in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`:

   ```
    # cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume 
    # RESUME=/dev/mapper/isw_chjgibahbj_DMRAIDp5
   ```

   which didn't map to correct swap in `/etc/fstab`, so I fixed that.
2. I don't have SELinux extensions installed, but I tried to boot with `selinux=0` and it didn't work.
3. My BIOS is the latest version.

I am guessing it has to do with RAID. I am using LVM on MDRAID mirror, so I am going to do more digging on my own, but I'm also putting it out there in case someone else can give me a quicker answer or point me in the right direction.

Comment: never mind. I forgot to run udpate-initramfs -u i can now boot

Answer (score 3):

I forgot to run update-initramfs -u after fixing the swap in .../resume and and /etc/fstab